# Can't find math.h constant with -std=c99?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I have the simple test code, `t.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  printf("%f\n", M_LN10);
}
```

On one of my systems (OS X 10.8.4, GCC 4.8.1), this compiles fine. Strangely, on another system (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, GCC 4.6.3) this compiles fine with `gcc t.c`, but if I do a `gcc -std=c99 t.c` I get:

```
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:18: error: ‘M_LN10’ undeclared (first use in this function)
t.c:5:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once 
for each function it appears in
```

I see no reason why GCC finds and accepts `M_LN10` in `math.h` no problem with the default C-standard, but not if C99 is enforced.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: The gcc default "standard" isn't standard. It's `gnu90`, which is "the 1990 C standard plus GNU extensions." Using XSI math.h defines without  setting _XOPEN_SOURCE is a GNU extension, not available when you specify an actual standard.

Comment: @rici Thanks, that adds some clarity. I'm used to `-std=c99` *adding* extensions, not taking them away.

Comment: There's a difference between adding extensions and adding standards :) (Or to put it another way, a new standard is an advance over the old one -- hopefully -- but not an extension.)

Comment: C standard says nothing about M_* constants. It defined by GNU C, BSD and other standards, but not C - so when you specify something that isn't GNU - gcc disables this feature, to be a little closer to standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `-D_BSD_SOURCE` or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` to your GCC command. Something like `gcc -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE t.c`

After looking in the math.h file on my system, `M_LN10` is defined as such:

```
#if defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_XOPEN
# define M_LN10         2.30258509299404568402  /* log_e 10 */
#endif
```

Comment: Please read `man feature_test_macros` or `info libc "Feature Test Macros"` so as to be able to give better advice. Macros whose names start with `__`  are pretty well never intended to be public. (`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are historical anomalies, before you bring them up.)

Comment: @shanet Don't you think such a definition will have other side effects?

Comment: @rici I learned something today. :) Updated my answer with the appropriate macros. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right; adding `-D_BSD_SOURCE` does the trick. On the OS X system `math.h` declares `M_LN10` without the `ifdef`... strange.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple is it with gcc on OS X too? Sort of weird, although makes some sense because OS X kernel is highly BSD related.

Comment: @keltar Yeah, GCC on OS X *doesn't* require any declaratives besides including `math.h` to get the `M_`... constants. It's that way both in `/usr/include/math.h` and in the version(s) provided by MacPorts `/opt/.../math.h`